# Logic behind the ID checksum?

Tags: coding-theory

I'm a resident of Kuwait and I just learnt that the CIVIL ID numbers allotted to us follow a checksum. The ID is 12 digit number following the algorithm below -

```
11 – Mod(( c1 * 2 ) + ( c2 * 1 ) + ( c3 * 6 ) + ( c4 * 3 ) + ( c5 * 7 ) +
( c6 * 9 ) + ( c7 * 10 ) + ( c8 * 5 ) + ( c9 * 8 ) + ( c10 * 4 ) + ( c11 * 2 )),11) = 
The 12th Digit
```

Here, Cx are the digits in the Civil ID number.

Can someone tell me what is the reasoning behind the coefficients used in the checksum? The Bulgarian civil number also uses a checksum but the algorithm used there uses powers of 2 modulus 11. More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_civil_number).

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about the system in Kuwait, but the similar one in Norway is designed to be an efficient error-detection scheme. That is, the most common typing errors (a single wrong digit and/or insertion/omission of a single digit) are guaranteed to be detected. I have dined with the guy who designed the Norwegian system (according to other colleagues sharing the table) :-). I believe the system we have here in Finland is somewhat similar, but not quite as robust as the Norwegian one. I would guess that the details of the analysis of the error events is quite messy.

Comment: Oh, and you should have read the tag description of *scheme* before using it (or any other tag). It was quite the wrong tag here, for scheme has a technical meaning in algebraic geometry - a much deeper part of math.

Comment: the idea behind the diffeent coeffcients is i think to combat misswitings, so 123 456 789 12x gives a different checksum than 123 546 789 12y  (4 and 5 exchanged), if all coefficients were the same then the two numbers  would get the same checksum)

Comment: I get the use of the coefficients here and how a checksum would prevent a typing error. However, I am interested in knowing why this particular set of coeff were chosen. I'm sure there's a reasoning behind it.

Comment: Apologies for using the wrong tag. This is my first post in math.stackexchange and I did not know which tag suited this question the most.

Comment: This is very similar to the ISBN-10 check digit scheme (which you can Google). The essential features are that the coefficients don't repeat and that 11 is prime, so that the integers mod 11 are a field. The one weakness of the Kuwait system is that it will not notice if you swap digits 2 and 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rephrasing your equation slightly, the check condition is $$(2,1,6,3,7,9,10,5,8,4,2)\cdot c_{1\ldots 11} + c_{12} \equiv 0\pmod {11}$$

If you take first differences of that vector modulo 11 you get $(10,5,8,4,2,1,6,3,7,9)$, which is $(2^5,2^4,2^3,2^2,2^1,2^0,2^9,2^8,2^7,2^6)$.

Comment: So I get how (10,5,8,4,..) comes from (2^5,2^4,) mod 11, Can you please explain how did the vector (2,1,6,3,7,9,10..) got transformed into (10,5,8,4,2,1..) ?

Comment: @Prakhar, "take first differences" means taking each adjacent pair and subtracting one from the other. So $1 - 2 \equiv 10, 6 - 1 \equiv 5, 3 - 6 \equiv 8, \ldots$.

Comment: Oh nice! If you don't mind me asking.. how did you figure this out? :D I mean, is it common to take first differences modulo 11 to a checksum algorithm?

Comment: @Prakhar, it's one of the first things I do when trying to understand a mystery sequence of numbers. It's a good way of identifying polynomials (if you repeat the operation $n$ times then an order-$n$ polynomial will give a constant vector).

Answer (score 2):

Check out the discussion on the [Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) and the [Verhoeff algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verhoeff_algorithm). The idea is to catch simple transcription errors (mistaken digits, leftouts, switched digits) that are common when copying long numbers by hand. The mathematics behind the Verhoeff algorithm is a bit unusual (it takes each digit to be an operation in a dihedral group, and applies to the digit in position $i$ the permutation $\sigma^i$, where $\sigma$ is a given permutation, and then operates the results) it is not hard to see it catches all simple errors (digit changes, transpositions).